# How to Copy All Folders From Server To Local Drive Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fetch a path from the Web.config file:

```
<appSettings>    
    <add key="Server" value="http://admin.xxxxxxx.com/1upload/*All File And Folder Copy this directory *"/>
    <add key="Local" value="C:\\Users\\IND_COM\\Desktop\\xxxx\\1upload\\paste The Copyed File"/>
</appSettings>
```

In the button click event I pass the source and destination path:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Source_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"].ToString();
    string Detination_Path = "@" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Local"].ToString();
    DirectoryCopy(Source_path, Detination_Path, true);
}

private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{          
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);//Exception Through In this Section..  

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "+ sourceDirName);
    }


    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }


    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

On my hosting server, I have a folder and all images and XML saved in different folders. For example, I have 1 directory named `1Upload`. Inside this directory I have 3 sub-directories and each has different files. I try to copy all 3 directories and files from the Server. This piece of code gives an exception

> URI is not supported

Comment: HTTP is not a file system.  You can make *web requests* to *download* content from HTTP and *save it* as a file.  But you can't perform a file system copy operation on something that isn't a file system.

Comment: Path Of Source Directtory "http://admin.xxxxxxx.com/1upload/

Comment: inside 1Upload Directore Have 3 Directory And 3 directory Have Some Contents.

Comment: I want Copy This 3 Directory With Contents And Save In Local Machine

Comment: Thanks david..But How to Download All Folder And File.Is it Possible To Download All Directory And FileS At A Time??

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is not a file system.

What you're looking to do is *not* to perform a file system copy operation, but rather to *download* the content from the web and *save it* to your file system.  For this, you want something like [the `WebClient.DownloadFile()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(sourceURL, destinationFile);
```

Each file would be a separate request.  You're currently trying to *list directory contents* of a website, which clearly won't work (because HTTP isn't a file system).  However you build your list of files, once you have that list you can loop over it and call `DownloadFile(source, destination)` for each file.

If you need the website to provide a list of files, you have to add that functionality to the website (if it's not already there, we don't know).  If you need to download all of the files in one operation, then the website would need to provide them in a single file (such as a `.zip` file).

Comment: I trying To Download Those File  help From Your Consept But I got A exception In Destinationon PAth.. Access to the path 'C:\Users\IND_COM\Desktop\New Folder\1upload' is denied